# ko.dependentObservable how this method understand dependencies cleverly?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am playing with knockoutjs with their samples and i have been edited orginal code bit of which is at below. fullName property assigned as dependentObservable and this method definitely knows which dependencies inside fullName method so fullName method works only if dependencies changed.

If i remove this.LastName() from  fullName method so changing lastName property does not cause invoke fullName method.

I wonder how this is happening.

```
var viewModel = {
    firstName: ko.observable("Bert"),
    lastName: ko.observable("Bertington")
};

viewModel.fullName = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
    alert('worked');
    return this.firstName() + " "+ this.lastName() ;
}, viewModel);


// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a dependency tracking mechanism in Knockout that is used while evaluating dependentObservables.  The key is that accessing an observable has to go through a function ( you have to call `this.firstName()`).  Along with returning the firstName, Knockout adds the dependentObservable as a subscriber to `firstName`.  When `firstName` is updated (which again has to go through the function), then all subscribers are notified.

Also, these dependencies are re-evaluated each time that a dependentObservable is evaluated, so the dependencies can actually change over time for a dependentObservable.

Comment: I find this behavior extremely danger as not all dependencies may be evaluated. Think of a calculated boolean property that's evaluated like "return @dependent1() || @dependent2()". If @dependent1() is true in the first evaluation, KO can't know the calculated property should also track @dependent2 changes. There should be another more explicit way of setting dependencies in my opinion.

Comment: @rosenfeld - in your case the value will never be different unless `dependent1` changes, so it is the only necessary dependency. Scenarios that are dangerous are if you branch on something that is not observable (if time of day is after 12 or something). It is always an option to declare both `dependent1` and `dependent2` in variables and then return the appropriate value so both are tracked as observables. hope that helps!